# PHP - Error from RegEx shown twice

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm sure this has nothing to do with PHP, but with my lack of skills :D
I made an input-form where one can note their personal data. To validate it, I've got a regular expression. When something is wrong I want to give the user an error note, telling him what he did wrong. But my programm prints it twice the whole time. 
There is the regex function:

```
protected function isFirstnameValid($firstname)
{
    $is_Valid = preg_match('/^[A-Za-z\-_\säöüß]{1,20}$/', $firstname);

    if($is_Valid === FALSE) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    } else if ($is_Valid === 0) {
        HTMLOutput::printErrorWhenWrongPattern(
            'Der Vorname ist nicht valide. Bitte geben Sie einen Namen
        zwischen 1 und 20 Zeichen an. Erlaubt sind nur Groß- und Kleinbuchstaben, 
        Leerzeichen, Umlaute und folgende Sonderzeichen: - _');

    } else {
        return $is_Valid === 1;
    }

}
```

Here is where I use that function:

```
public function isValidPersonalData()
{
    try
    {
        if(isset($_POST[Person::INDEX_FIRSTNAME]) && $this->isFirstnameValid($_POST[Person::INDEX_FIRSTNAME]))
        {
            saveDataToSession(Person::INDEX_FIRSTNAME);
        }
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo 'Der reguläre Ausdruck ist nicht valide. Bitte wenden Sie sich an den Adminstrator.';
    }

    try
    {
        if(isset($_POST[Person::INDEX_SURNAME]) && $this->isSurnameValid($_POST[Person::INDEX_SURNAME]))
        {
            saveDataToSession(Person::INDEX_SURNAME);
        }
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo 'Der reguläre Ausdruck ist nicht valide. Bitte wenden Sie sich an den Adminstrator.';
    }

    try
    {
        if(isset($_POST[Person::INDEX_UNIVERSITY]) && $this->isUniversityValid($_POST[Person::INDEX_UNIVERSITY]))
        {
            saveDataToSession(Person::INDEX_UNIVERSITY);
        }
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo 'Der reguläre Ausdruck ist nicht valide. Bitte wenden Sie sich an den Adminstrator.';
    }

    return !empty($_SESSION[Person::INDEX_FIRSTNAME])
        && !empty($_SESSION[Person::INDEX_SURNAME])
        && !empty($_SESSION[Person::INDEX_UNIVERSITY]);
}
```

The Error-HTML-function (don't laugh because of the name :D ):

```
public static function printErrorWhenWrongPattern($text)
{
print <<<HTML
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Fehler:</span>
$text;
</div>
```

HTML;
    }

And the code where I'm using the isValidPersonalData() function:

```
if ($personalDataValidator->isValidPersonalData() && $bookDataValidator->isValidBookData()) {
    $htmlOutput->printPageCaption('Ausgabe der Daten');
    $htmlOutput->printPersonalDataTable(
        $_SESSION[Person::INDEX_FIRSTNAME],
        $_SESSION[Person::INDEX_SURNAME],
        $_SESSION[Person::INDEX_UNIVERSITY]
    );
    $htmlOutput->printBookDataTable(
        $_SESSION[Book::INDEX_BOOKONE],
        $_SESSION[Book::INDEX_BOOKTWO],
        $_SESSION[Book::INDEX_BOOKTHREE]
    );
    stopSession();
} else if ($personalDataValidator->isValidPersonalData()) {
    $htmlOutput->printPageCaption('Eingabe der Buch-Daten');
    $htmlOutput->printBookDataForm();

} else {
    $htmlOutput->printPageCaption('Eingabe der persönlichen Daten');
    $htmlOutput->printPersonalDataForm();
}
$htmlOutput->printPageFooter();
```

[The error shown twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tb7y.jpg)

Hope I provided all the necessary data. Don't worry about security problems in my code. It's just an exercise for the university and I don't intend to use PHP again as soon as I finish this course :D But sadly I can't find the mistake on my own :(

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't copy paste same code to `isSurnameValid`?

Comment: When `$personalDataValidator->isValidPersonalData()` fails in first __`if`__ and shows it's message, the following __`elseif`__ works, where `$personalDataValidator->isValidPersonalData()` fails __again__ and shows message for the second time.

Comment: So it's because of the if-statement. I thought about this being the problem, but this part of the code was shown to us by our professor. So I thought I should leave it like this. Thanks a lot. I'm going to change that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `isValidPersonalData()` is calling two times(1. in **if** and 2. in **else if**) So if first condition becomw flase it will aging execute `isValidPersonalData()` in else if statement. You can execute it single time and store result in variable then use that variable

```
$is_valid = $personalDataValidator->isValidPersonalData(); // add this
if ($is_valid && $bookDataValidator->isValidBookData()) { //change here
    $htmlOutput->printPageCaption('Ausgabe der Daten');
    $htmlOutput->printPersonalDataTable(
        $_SESSION[Person::INDEX_FIRSTNAME],
        $_SESSION[Person::INDEX_SURNAME],
        $_SESSION[Person::INDEX_UNIVERSITY]
    );
    $htmlOutput->printBookDataTable(
        $_SESSION[Book::INDEX_BOOKONE],
        $_SESSION[Book::INDEX_BOOKTWO],
        $_SESSION[Book::INDEX_BOOKTHREE]
    );
    stopSession();
} else if ($is_valid) { //change this 
    $htmlOutput->printPageCaption('Eingabe der Buch-Daten');
    $htmlOutput->printBookDataForm();

} else {
    $htmlOutput->printPageCaption('Eingabe der persönlichen Daten');
    $htmlOutput->printPersonalDataForm();
}
$htmlOutput->printPageFooter();
```

Comment: I'll try to change that. Thanks :)